# Asking external program to perform some job in python script in Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, automation

I would like to write a script in python in ubuntu for performing some series of a task by an external program(installed in Ubuntu) multiple times. 
I can run the program for one file from the terminal but I would like to automate it by writing the python script so that it can read the files and perform the job. How should I proceed?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [system](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system) command, or better the [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) command to call your existing application. 
Subprocess would be better for your use case as you can use stdout, stderr and get status code for errors.

Comment: @natonomo
Thank you 
 I tried the 2nd option but get the following error

from: can't read /var/mail/os 
from: can't read /var/mail/subprocess
 ./integration.py: line 5: program: command not found  
./integration.py: line 6: folder: command not found
 ./integration.py: line 9: syntax error near unexpected token (' 
./integration.py: line 9: files = [f for f in listdir(folder) if f.endswith('.tif')]'

Does anyone has any idea

Answer (score 0):

Use [subprocess.run()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run):

```
from subprocess import run

program = './program'
files = ['f1.txt', 'f2.txt', 'f3.txt']

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for filename in files:
        run([program, filename], shell=True)
```

You could also run the program on a set of files, e.g. those that have a specific file ending, like `.txt`:

```
from os import listdir
from subprocess import run

program = './program'
folder = 'folder/'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    files = [folder + f for f in listdir(folder) if f.endswith('.txt')]
    for filename in files:
        run([program, filename], shell=True)
```

Comment: @Dipankar Saha I just saw your comment and since it wasn't actually on my response I can't respond there. Could you please provide a formatted version of what you used to get the new errors and the traceback?